# Sum numbers with JavaScript doesn't work properly "Intl.NumberFormat"

Tags: javascript, html

I have page with table of products and for each product there is a price.
When I change the qty it gets the total price...

But I have this problem:
When the numbers are lower then "1,000", the sum is ok.

ex:

1. prod 1: 200
2. prod 2: 200
3. prod 3: 500
4. **total: 900**

But when the numbers are greater then "1,000", the comma is the problem. I get a wrong answer.

ex:

1. prod 1: 200
2. prod 2: 1,200
3. prod 3: 300
4. **total: 501**

When I remove the "Intl.NumberFormat" from the total of each product, I get the right answer, but for some cases I get numbers like this: "1.000031545",
which I don't need. I only need the first 2 digit after the dot.

**CODE: (simplefied)**

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td style="text-align: center;">
           <label for="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]"><input class='qty' style="font-size: 12px;" type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $prodid; ?>" placeholder="qty" minlength="1" maxlength="3" size="2"></label>
       </td>
       <td class='price'>
           <?php echo $prodprice; ?>
       </td>
       <td width="40" class="sum">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3">
           <span class="output"></span>
       </td>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML);
    });

    $('#total').text(total);

            givenNumber = total; 
            nfObject = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US'); 
            output = nfObject.format(givenNumber); 
            document.querySelector('.output').textContent = total; 
}

getTotal();

$('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var price = $('.price', parent);
    var sum = $('.sum', parent);
    var value = parseInt(this.value) * parseFloat(price.get(0).innerHTML||0);
            givenNum1 = value; 
            nfObj = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US'); 
            outpu = nfObj.format(givenNum1); 
    sum.text(outpu);
    getTotal();
})

</script>
```

Comment: Why is it wrong? What do you expect instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> If parseFloat encounters a character other than a plus sign (+), minus
> sign (- U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), numeral (0–9), decimal point (.), or
> exponent (e or E), it returns the value up to that character, ignoring
> the invalid character and characters following it.

You can remove the comma by using `replace()` and then parse it afterwards to get the right value.

```js
let str = "1,200"
let newStr = str.replace(/,/g,"");


console.log(`Without replace ${parseFloat(str)}`);
console.log(`With replace ${newStr}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseFloat` stops parsing at the first invalid character. `,` is not a valid character to `parseFloat`.

You can remove the `,`:

```
total += parseFloat(this.textContent.replace(/,/g, ""));
```

Note that I also switched from `innerHTML` to `textContent`.

Also note that I used a regular expression with the `g` ("global") flag, since `.replace(",", "")` would only replace the *first* comma (so `1,200,300` would fail). Or in modern environments you can use `replaceAll` but it's relatively new (though easily polyfilled):

```
total += parseFloat(this.textContent.replaceAll(",", ""));
```

For this I'd just use the regular expression.